# Saving ArrayAdapter to Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, internal-storage

I am making a weather app, and wanted to know how to save an ArrayAdapter to the Internal Storage, I understand that I must use a fileOutputStream to save it, but I need to know how to convert it to bytes so it can be saved. If it is not possible, then is there any way to save the ArrayAdapter Persistently another way? The ArrayAdapter only contains strings.

Sorry, if this is just me being stupid and missing something obvious, but I'm new to the whole android thing, coming from c#, this is a lot more confusing, although I understand why things are done as they are.

Answer (score 1):

> wanted to know how to save an ArrayAdapter to the Internal Storage,

You do not save an `ArrayAdapter` to a file.

> The ArrayAdapter only contains strings

No, it adapts a `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>`. *That* is your model data, and *that* you can save to some sort of file, such as:

- a [plain file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), such as in XML or JSON format
- a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) (as a `Set<String>`, so this will only work well if the order of the strings is able to be rebuilt later, such as them being in alphabetical order)

Answer (score 0):

As Commonsware stated you need to save either the Array or Arraylist you used. If you are saving to a file I would suggest you read this blog post http://androidjavaio.blogspot.co.uk . It includes a very simple class for saving and writing data from arrays to file using Random Access.